# Python manipulate axis (x and y) update

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

we measure the radius over an entire device (each degree, 360 points), which is around 148mm. It should be between 146 and 150.

If you plot the data with the corresponding limits, you get this: 
[CirclPlot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgNQR.jpg)

I like to change the axis that between -145 and 145 is small, and between 145- 150 / -145 - -150 is large. So I can see the measured value nice in between the limits.

Is that possible with python?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.scale as mscale
import pandas as pd

#read CSV

EBRData = pd.read_csv('C://Users/vanderey/Documents/MATLAB/EBRTest2.csv', header = 0)

# Define data

Dates = EBRData['Date']
Rx = EBRData['xCoat']
Ry = EBRData['yCoat']
RLSLx = EBRData['xCoat_LSL']
RLSLy = EBRData['yCoat_LSL']
RUSLx = EBRData['xCoat_USL']
RUSLy = EBRData['yCoat_USL']


#Create plot

my_dpi=96
plt.figure(figsize=(480/my_dpi, 480/my_dpi), dpi=my_dpi)

plt.plot(Rx, Ry, color='blue', marker='.', linewidth=1, alpha=0.4)
plt.plot(RLSLx, RLSLy, color='red', marker='.', linewidth=1, alpha=0.4)
plt.plot(RUSLx, RUSLy, color='red', marker='.', linewidth=1, alpha=0.4)


plt.title('EBR')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes, make two subplots in one figure, one for -150 < x < -145, the other for 145 < x < 150. I would not recommend to try to squeeze a single axis of a plot to have different scalings. This is not only horrible to create (not only in matplotlib but anywhere I guess) but also misleading/misunderstandable to read.

Comment: But now I think I understand - you don't want to do this at a single axis but on the whole circle... what about simply substracting the minimum value or at least 140...?

Comment: Why not just work out the radial distance of each point from (0, 0) (simple trigonometry), and then plot that vs. the azimuth. Then, you can just set the limits of the y axis to be 145–150.

Answer (score 0):

If *radius* is what you want to show, I'd also recommend to calculate `R` from `x` and `y` measurements and put that into a plot together with the target limits.
You can do so by calculating the complete polar coordinates from your x/y-values

```
phi = np.arctan2(df.yCoat, df.xCoat)
R = pd.DataFrame(np.sqrt(df.xCoat.values**2 + df.yCoat.values**2), columns=['R'], index=phi)
```

If you rather like to plot over the nominal angular values instead of the actual measured angle positions, you could set phi also to e.g.

```
phi = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 360, endpoint=False)
```

However, this can be plotted simply as a normal line plot with two indicated limit lines like

```
R.plot()
plt.hlines(146, -np.pi, np.pi, 'k')
plt.hlines(150, -np.pi, np.pi, 'k')
```

[image]

or e.g. as a polar plot

```
f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.set_rlim(144, 152)
plt.plot(R, 'b.-')
ax.fill_between(np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 360), 140, 146, color='gray')
ax.fill_between(np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 360), 150, 160, color='gray')
```

[image]

To show samples outside the wanted range, you can simply add e.g.

```
plt.plot(R[R<146], 'r.')
plt.plot(R[R>150], 'r.')
```

to immediately see if there's a problem:

[image]